# Python & Selenium: ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted error

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I use Selenium in Python for scraping.

The following error is displayed when I try to click button tag.

`ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button id="pos-list" class="menu-btn-normal">...</button> is not clickable at point`

**HTML**

```
<div id="order-bar">
    <div id="order-bar-menu">
        <button id="order-list" class="menu-btn-select">orderlist</button>
        <button id="pos-list" class="menu-btn-normal">positionlist</button>
        ...
```

**Python**

```
pos = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="pos-list"]')))
print(pos.text)
pos.click()
```

`print(pos.text)` is printed as `positionlist` I expected.

How can I click this button element?

It would be appreciated if you could give me some hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
pos = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[text()="positionlist"]')))
pos.click()
```

OR

```
pos = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="order-bar"]/div/button')))
pos[1].click()
```

OR js execute and click()

```
pos = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="pos-list"]')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", pos)
```

Comment: Same error message was displayed though I tried both suggestion. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @ SamuraiBlue, I've updated

Comment: I tried js execute and click() and it worked!! Thank you for your update!!